# A noun must be missing in which/that or what clauses?

Tags: sentence-structure, relative-clauses

Can I simply conclude that a noun must be missing in which/that/who or what clauses, even though the missing noun might be an object behind an infinitive verb, gerund verb or a preposition?

I wrote these following sentences, but I am not sure if they are grammatical or not.

> This is not the show that the students want to see.

the infinitive **to see** here acts as an object of the verb want, but **see** is a transitive verb , therefore it must be followed by an object, and **that** represent the  missing object, which makes the sentence correct? Right?

> This is strategy which people start adopting.

Gerund verb **adopting** here acts as an object of the verb start, but **adopting** is a transitive verb , therefore it must be followed by a object ,and **which** represents the missing object, am I correct?

> He is the man whom we have grown sick of.
>
> He is the man whom we have grown sick of talking about.

A noun must always follow a preposition, so even though I placed one preposition behind the PP phrase **of talking** in the second example , the rule will still apply, which makes the sentence correct?

> The students are trying to understand the rules that the teacher judged acceptable.

**Judged** is a kind of verb that should be followed by an object and a complement,and in the clause we only see the complement instead of the object , and **that** represents the missing object,which makes the sentence correct, am I right?

Comment: You must include an article *(**the** or **a**)* before ***strategy*** in your second example. Note that the relevant "relativizer" *(**that, which, whom**)* is optional in *every* example (you could simply omit it). But I don't understand exactly what you're asking here.

Comment: No, Fionna, "to see" is complement, not object, of "want". The covert relative word  is object of "see".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I learned that relative pronoun represents a part in a relative clause, so when writing a relative clause, if I make sure something(noun) is missing , the sentence must be correct?

Comment: Do you have access to a good grammar book?

Comment: @BillJ I have one grammar book written in Chinese, but the example sentences in the book are the simple ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *This is not the show* [*that the students want to see ___*] .

"That" is not a relative pronoun but a subordinator, so in the bracketed relative clause, the '___' notation (called 'gap') indicates the covert presence of the relativised element functioning as object of "see". Gap has "show" as antecedent. Incidentally, the infinitival clause "to see" is complement, not direct object, of "want". Note that clauses cannot be objects.

> *This is the strategy* [*which people start adopting ___*].

The object of the verb "adopting" is represented by 'gap', which is linked to "which", which has “strategy” as antecedent. Note that "adapting” is complement, not object, of "start".

> *He is the man* [*whom we have grown sick of ___*].

The complement of the preposition "of" is represented by 'gap', which is linked to the relative pronoun "whom", which has "man" as antecedent.

> *He is the man* [*whom we have grown sick of talking about ___*].

The complement of the preposition "about" is represented by 'gap', which is linked to the relative pronoun "whom", which has "man" as antecedent.

> *The students are trying to understand the rules* [*that the teacher*
>   *judged ___ acceptable*].

The object of "judged" is represented by 'gap', which has "rules" as its antecedent.

Comment: Thank you so much, so the relative clauses act as an adjective to add information into the noun which precedes it, and those nouns are antecedents, and the antecedents are also the object in the gap, is that right?

Comment: By the way, my grammar book says that if infinitive clause is behind a transitive verb, the infinitive clause is an object, but i guess my book is mistaken .

Comment: @Fionna Some traditional grammars do, but non-finite clauses that follow another verb are best called 'catenative complements. Please see here:  [link](https://www.brighthubeducation.com/esl-lesson-plans/56360-catenative-verbs-linking-verbs-in-english/), and here: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenative_verb)

Comment: Okay ! Thanks again , and is my way of understanding your answer correct ?

Comment: @Fionna, Yes, relative clauses are sometimes called 'adjective clauses', and yes, the nouns that are located just before the relative clauses are the antecedents. But it's better to say that the relative pronoun (not the antecedent) serves as the object in the relative clause. The meaning of the relative pronoun is provided by the antecedent.