# "As close as possible to [the point] where" - the noun is omitted, how would you call such an omission?

Tags: nouns, terminology

I have noticed that "as close as possible" is sometimes followed by "to where" instead of a noun. The bold text in square brackets is added by me.

> To speed up the flow of data, electrons need to be turned into photons "as close as possible to **[the point]** where the signal is processed", explains Bert Offrein of IBM Research.

> Health services would ideally be available as close as possible to **[the places]** where people live and be affordable.

I know that relative pronouns are sometimes omitted as well, e.g.

> I suppose **[that]** you don't like Jim.

In style guides addressed to writing for global audience, it is sometimes advised to not omit relative pronouns since they make the text more clear.

If I want to give a recommendation to not omit the nouns after "as close as possible" (for the same reason) (and in similar cases), how would I call these nouns? Or how I can describe such an omission in other way?

Comment: Syntactically, there's no real difference between ***as close as possible*** and ***near*** in your context (except that the former *must* be followed by preposition ***to***, whereas *Health services are available **near** where I live* is fine without optional ***to***). But note that you ***never need*** to include a noun phrase such as ***the places*** before ***where*** - the first word in ***Where** I live is near London* functions perfectly well as the subject noun in that sentence without me explicitly specifying ***The town** where I live...* So arguably there is no "omission" anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica So in other words such an omission is more acceptable than omission of relative pronouns?

Comment: Like I said, it's not really a case of "omission". It's just that there's no absolute *reason* to introduce additional text between ***to*** and ***where*** in your example context. This is nothing to do with the fact that [the relativiser ***that*** is optional in many contexts.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/197706/a-noun-must-be-missing-in-which-that-or-what-clauses)